Calculation of the complex field using Huygens sources
I would like to calculate the complex field at the point $\vec{r}=(x, y, z)$ in three-dimensional space. The field is generated by two point sources with position vectors $\vec{s}=(s_{x}, s_{y}, s_{z})$ and $\vec{s}'=(s_{x}', s_{y}', s_{z}')=(s_{x}+d, s_{y}', s_{z})$. As you can see, the point sources are at the same height, have different y-coordinates, and are shifted along the x-axis. The wave vector is of the form $\vec{k}=(k_{x}, 0, k_{z})$. I am wondering if I can express the field component of the dashed point source by the field component of the undashed point source, assuming I know the phase shift between the two point sources (maybe with some approximations).
The phase shift between the two point sources is
$$\Delta \phi=\vec{k}\cdot(\vec{s}'-\vec{s})=\left(\begin{matrix}k_{x}\\0\\k_{z}\end{matrix}\right)\cdot \left(\begin{matrix}d\\s_{y}'-s_{y}\\0\end{matrix}\right)=k_{x}\cdot d$$
therefore, it depends only on the x-component of the wave vector. The complex field of the undashed point source has the form
$$
\exp(i(k\cdot|\vec{r}-\vec{s}|))
$$
while that of the dashed point source has the form
$$
\exp(i(k\cdot|\vec{r}-\vec{s}'|+\Delta \phi))=\exp(i(k\cdot|\vec{r}-\vec{s}'|))\exp(i\Delta \phi)
$$
Can we somehow come to a total field of the form
\begin{align*}E_{gesamt}&=\exp(i(k\cdot|\vec{r}-\vec{s}|))+\exp(i(k\cdot|\vec{r}-\vec{s}|))\exp(i\Delta \phi)\\
&=\exp(i(k\cdot|\vec{r}-\vec{s}|))(1+\exp(i\Delta \phi))
\end{align*}
Best regards,
Simplex
Edit: If it helps you can consider the y-components of both point sources identical ($s_y=s_y'$)
